# Chart Init not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, charts

I am adding DIV tags dynamically on button's click event with unique ids.

jquery:- res=1,2,3... for loop variable value.

```
chartname='chart'+res;
myVarchart = setTimeout(function(){chartinit(chartname)}, 200);
```

HTML:-

```
<div id="chart'+res+'" style="height:200px;width:400px;"> </div>
```

Means ids of div tag will be chart1,2,3... according to for loop variable value.

But chart only display for last 2 - 3 divs. **Its issue of initialisation time taking by echart library. how to overcome ??**

Comment: Idea 1) it javascript allows to manage Threading manually.

Comment: can I see the full code of the loop? and rendering the dynamic div.. i am using Angularjs + echarts and I have made this. I think I can help you out of it

Answer (score 0):

I have used angularjs and echarts in making dynamic charts via `echarts`.
`$scope.widgets` is an array of object which includes chart options ,id and its index.

I also added `javascript-detect-element-resize` library for adding `resize` event every `div`
https://github.com/sdecima/javascript-detect-element-resize

```
  $scope.widgets.map(function(widget) {
      $timeout(function() {
          let chart2 = echarts.init(document.getElementById('widget_id_'+widget.index+'_'+ widget.elements.chart.id));
          let resizeElement = document.getElementById('widget_id_'+widget.index+'_'+ widget.elements.chart.id),
            resizeCallback = function() {
                chart2.resize();
            };
            addResizeListener(resizeElement, resizeCallback);
      }, 600)
  });
```